# Recursively substracting: myarray[i+1]-myarray[i]

Tags: python, recursion, computer-science

I am usually computing iterations over lists or arrays in such a way that I am often subtracting the ***ith*** element of the list to the next, the ***ith+1***.

The operation that I am referring to is:

```py
for i in range(len(myarray)-1): # number of columns -1
    newarray = myarray[i+1]-myarray[i]
```

Where the array could be also a list. If using pandas series the code just transforms to `mySeries.iloc[i+1,:] - mySeries.iloc[i,:]` but the general procedure does not change.

I've been wondering if there is a vectorized way or simply a better way to do such operation, in order to improve code "appearance" and efficiency.

Comment: `[myarray[i+1]-myarray[i] for i in range(len(myarray-1))]`, or `[elem1-elem2 for elem1,elem2 in zip(myarray[1:], myarray)]`. The latter will create a `myarray[1:]` list, thus taking more space.

Comment: mySeries-mySeries.shift()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `numpy` for this,

```
import numpy as np

myarray = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,78,95])

newarray = myarray[1:] - myarray[:-1]
```